# How to show object content under object in Firebase Database by *ngFor

Tags: angular, database, firebase, ngfor, snapshot

[I have this structure of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmFA0.jpg)

I want to rich replyMessage, have this error " Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'Ed'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

How to make replyMessage iterables.
Messages I got by snapshot....

TS.

```js
import {Component, Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
import {AngularFireDatabase} from "@angular/fire/database";
import {root} from "rxjs/internal-compatibility";
import {map} from "rxjs/operators";


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

@Component({
  selector: 'app-discussions-page',
  templateUrl: './discussions-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./discussions-page.component.css']
})
export class DiscussionsPageComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  email;
  message;
  messages = [];
  private users;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      message: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required,])),
    });

    this.users = localStorage.getItem('user') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) : {};
    //  console.log(this.users.user);


    this.db.list('messages').snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes =>
        changes.map(c =>
          ({key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()})
        )
      )
    ).subscribe(data => {
      this.messages = data;
      console.log(this.messages);
    });


    }


  replyTxt(reply, key) {
    const timestamp = this.getTimeStamp();
    this.db.list(`messages/${(key)}/replyMessages`).push({
      reply,
      name: this.users.user.displayName,
      timestamp: timestamp
    });
    // console.log(reply, key)
  }


  onSubmit() {

    const timestamp = this.getTimeStamp();
    this.db.list('messages').push({

      name: this.users.user.displayName,
      message: this.message,
      timestamp: timestamp
    });
    this.message = '';
  }


  getTimeStamp() {
    const now = new Date();
    const date = now.getFullYear() + '/' +
      (now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +
      now.getDate();
    const time = now.getHours() + ':' +
      now.getMinutes() + ':' +
      now.getSeconds();
    return (date + ' ' + time);
  }

}
```

And this is my HTML code:

```html
<div class="col-9 offset-2">
  <h4>Մեկնաբանություններ</h4>
</div>
<div class="answers" *ngFor="let item of messages; let i = index">
  <ul>
    <b>{{ item.name }}</b>
    <b>{{ item.key }}</b>

    <p>{{ item.timestamp | date:'yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss a' }}</p>

    <p>{{item.message}}</p>


  </ul>

  <div class="reply">
    <input type="text" name="reply-{{i}}" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.reply"/>
    <button class="btn" (click)="replyTxt(item.reply, item.key)"> Reply</button>
  </div>


  <div *ngFor="let item of messages">
    <div *ngFor="let rep of item.replyMessages.key">
      {{rep.name}}
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: The problem is in the html not in ts, add that also to see what you are using

Comment: <div *ngFor="let rep of replyMessage ">

        <p>{{rep.reply}}</p>

    </div>

Comment: Where are u using replymessages in the above code

Comment: Two quick things about posting here on SO. Please do not post links as they can break and if it does, it would invalidate the question so include Firebase structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. Second thing: code in comments is very hard to read! Update your question with that code please.

Comment: Thanks, Jay, it is my first question :)